# Outlook .items.restrict using two filters

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm using a script that opens an email and downloads its attachment. Right now I can either choose to download the most recent attachment on the most recent email:

```
Sub CTEmailAttDownload()

Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6
'~~> Path for the attachment
Const AttachmentPath As String = "C:\TEMP\TestExcel"

    Dim oOlAp As Object
    Dim oOlns As Object
    Dim oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object
    Dim oOlAtch As Object
    Dim oOlResults As Object

    Dim x As Long

    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = "Daily Tracker " & Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy")

    'You can only have a single instance of Outlook, so if it's already open
    'this will be the same as GetObject, otherwise it will open Outlook.
    Set oOlAp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'No point searching the whole Inbox - just since yesterday.
    Set oOlResults = oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format(Date - 1, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'")

    'If you have more than a single attachment they'll all overwrite each other.
    'x will update the filename.
    x = 1
    For Each oOlItm In oOlResults
        If oOlItm.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
                If GetExt(oOlAtch.FileName) = "xlsx" Then
                    oOlAtch.SaveAsFile AttachmentPath & "\" & NewFileName & ".xlsx"
                End If
                x = x + 1
            Next oOlAtch
        End If
    Next oOlItm

End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' GetExt
'
'   Returns the extension of a file.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function GetExt(FileName As String) As String

    Dim mFSO As Object
    Set mFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    GetExt = mFSO.GetExtensionName(FileName)
End Function
```

By using **`'[Subject] ='`** I can download it by subject.

My question is, how can I put those two filters together so I can filter by Subject and ReceivedTime?

I tried binding them together with **`,`, `&`, `+`** and so far I haven't been successful.

Comment: what about restricting `oOlResults` again. Like `Set oOlResults = oOlResults.Items.Restrict("[Subject]='" & mySubject)` underneath the first `Set oOlResults`? You could also add it to the If statement `If oOlItm.Attachments.Count > 0 And oOlItm.Subject = mySubject`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@SQL=(Subject LIKE '%blah%') AND (ReceivedTime > '01/02/2015')
```

Comment: Hi, Dmitry. Where would I put that? And in this case it won't calculate it to be emails from the last day.

Comment: You would pass that filter to Items.Restrict to get back a collection restricted on two conditions - subject and received date.

Answer (score 0):

It is a struggle to get the syntax for even one restrict. As indicated in the comment by Scott Holtzman, if you know each filter separately, you can filter twice.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CTEmailAttDownload()

    Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6
    '~~> Path for the attachment
    Const AttachmentPath As String = "C:\TEMP\TestExcel"

    Dim oOlAp As Object
    Dim oOlns As Object
    Dim oOlInb As Object

    Dim oOlItm As Object
    Dim oOlAtch As Object

    Dim oOlResults As Object
    Dim oOlSubjectResults  As Object
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim i As Long

    Dim x As Long

    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = "Daily Tracker " & format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy")

    'You can only have a single instance of Outlook, so if it's already open
    'this will be the same as GetObject, otherwise it will open Outlook.
    Set oOlAp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'No point searching the whole Inbox - just since yesterday.
    Set oOlResults = oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & format(Date - 1, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'")

    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%test%'"

    Set oOlSubjectResults = oOlResults.Restrict(strFilter)

    If oOlSubjectResults.count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No emails found with applicable subject"

    Else
        'If you have more than a single attachment they'll all overwrite each other.
        'x will update the filename.
        x = 1

        For i = 1 To oOlSubjectResults.count
            Set oOlItm = oOlSubjectResults(i)
            If oOlItm.Attachments.count > 0 Then
                Debug.Print oOlItm.Subject
                For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments

                    Debug.Print oOlAtch.DisplayName

                    If GetExt(oOlAtch.FileName) = "xlsx" Then
                        oOlAtch.SaveAsFile AttachmentPath & "\" & NewFileName & ".xlsx"
                    End If
                    x = x + 1
                Next oOlAtch
            End If
        Next i
    End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set oOlAp = Nothing
    Set oOlns = Nothing
    Set oOlInb = Nothing

    Set oOlResults = Nothing
    Set oOlSubjectResults = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, @niton. I'm sorry, but I've only got to work on this again now. Using this exact code I can't get it to open Outlook 2013 at all. I checked the references and it seems that I have the right libraries.  Do you know what might be happening?