# Outlook VBA Date Time filter

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an outlook macro that reads the all the Subject lines of all unread emails.

```
Sub ReadMails()
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objFolderSrc = objFolder.Folders("My Own Folder")

    Dim Subjects() As String
    ReDim Subjects(1 To 1) As String

    Set colItems = objFolderSrc.Items
    Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = False")

    For Each objMessage In colFilteredItems
        Subjects(UBound(Subjects)) = objMessage.ConversationTopic
        ReDim Preserve Subjects(1 To UBound(Subjects) + 1) As String
    Next
End Sub
```

Instead I need to read the emails that have come between current time and 8 AM in the morning of the same day.

How do I add that filter

Comment: What is `olFolderInbox`?

Comment: @Vityata Its the folder where all received emails go to. This is root inbox folder Do not worry about it. All that works

Comment: Well, I was just trying to replicate what you already have and to continue from there. In general take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx Especially this line: `sFilter = "[LastModificationTime] > '" & Format("1/15/99 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"`

Comment: @Vityata can i add multiple filters???

Comment: Looks possible here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508808/outlook-items-restrict-using-two-filters

Comment: @Vityata thanks m8

Comment: What is Current time? same day at 8am or 8am is next day?

Comment: @Vityata same day 8 am.. But I figured it out....

Comment: @Vityata needed some help with regex - need to extract the username out of email address. Eg - extract prateek from prateek@gmail.com

Comment: `Split("doNotAskQuestionsInComments@stackoverflow.com","@")(0)`

Comment: @Vityata - passive anger :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [TimeValue Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz2ahtzs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim EightAM As Date

    EightAM = TimeValue("08:00:00 AM")

    If (TimeValue(Now()) <= EightAM) Then
        ' Do something / Read Email
        Debug.Print TimeValue(Now())
    Else
        ' Do something else
        Debug.Print "bla bla !!!"
    End If
End Sub
```