# OUTLOOK vba filter with like statement

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to put a like statement as I want to filter email that starts with `tmeadmin@`

This code breaks on the line with the `like` statement. How do I fix it?

```
 Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim InboxMsg As Object
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder
    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items
     Dim filter As String
     filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail LIKE 'tmeadmin@%'"

      MsgBox (filter)
 Set myRestrictItems = Inbox.Items.Restrict(filter)
```

Comment: To be clear I've never used this method before, but it doesn't mention the `Like` operator in the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict so it might not be supported?

Comment: Supposedly you can use `"@SQL="` as a prefix to do some interesting queries that allow you to use like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items but on my machine these examples wont work https://stackoverflow.com/a/35509993/2727437

Comment: more examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison

Comment: i updated the script but i still get the error as the filter is not being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

To use the LIKE operator, you need to use the @SQL syntax:

```
filter = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail LIKE 'tmeadmin@%'"
```