# Use VBA in Excel to find Outlook Email with specific keywords in Subject line & attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Using a macro within Excel, I am trying to search Outlook for the most recent email with "Blue Recruit Req Data" in the Subject line, however there will be additional words in the subject line so need to search for any subject line that contains that string but doesn't exactly match that string.  Also, when an email is found with the "Blue Recruit Req Data" string in the subject line, I need to verify that it has an attachment.  If the subject line is found & the email contains an attachment, then I want to store the Subject & the received date in variables and compare them to previous subject & date stored in the Excel file that is running the macro.  If the subject lines don't match & the date of the email is after the date last stored in the excel file, then I want to save that attachment in a folder.  I am running into problems that it is not finding any emails that contain "Blue Recruit Req Data" in the subject but I know there are multiple emails in my Outlook with that phrase in the subject line.  Any suggestions on what I'm not coding correctly or missing?

```
Sub CheckEmail_BlueRecruit()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim olAp As Object, olns As Object, olInb As Object
Dim olItm As Object, olAtch As Object, olMail As Object
'Outlook Variables for email
Dim sSubj As String, dtRecvd As String
Dim oldSubj As String, olddtRecvd As String



Sheets("Job Mapping").Visible = True
Sheets("CC Mapping").Visible = True
Sheets("Site Mapping").Visible = True
Sheets("Historical Blue Recruit Data").Visible = True
Sheets("Historical HRT Data").Visible = False
Sheets("Combined Attrition Data").Visible = True

Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets(1)

'Designate ECP Facilities Model file as FNAME
myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
MainWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Name

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = myPath

'designate file path for Attrition Files
    FacModPath = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Sheets(1).Delete


'Get Outlook Instance
Set olAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
Set olns = olAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInb = olns.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set olMail = olInb.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = ""*Blue Recruit Req Data*""")

'Chec if there are any matching emails
If Not (olMail Is Nothing) Then

    For Each olItm In olMail
        If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
            dtRecvd = olItm.ReceivedTime
            sSubj = olItm.Subject
            oldSubj = Sheets("CC Mapping").Range("M2").Value
            olddtRecvd = Sheets("CC Mapping").Range("M3").Value
            If sSubj = oldSubj Or dtRecvd <= olddtRecvd Then
                MsgBox "No new Blue Recruit data files to load."
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Range("M2").Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = sSubj
                Range("M3").Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = dtRecvd
                For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
                    If InStr(myAttachment.DisplayName, ".xlsx") Then
                        I = I + 1
                        myAttachment.SaveAs Filename:=FacModPath & "\" & myAttachment.DisplayName
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        MsgBox "No attachment found."
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

Else

    MsgBox "No emails found."
    Exit Sub

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

A separate, but related question, if I want to search for emails that are in the Outlook Archive folder, or even a subfolder of Inbox, do I need to format this line of code any differently?

```
Set olInb = olns.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52066997/1521579

Comment: You need to [set the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) to the Outlook Library inside Excel.

Comment: I was able to add the SQL code instead and it is now searching through the emails in my in Inbox, but when performing the For loop (For Each itm in filteredItems) it isn't returning the most recent email with Blue Recruit Req Data in the subject line, it is skipping the most recent and returning the second email.  I verified both emails have Blue Recruit Req Data spelled the same in their subject lines.  Any idea why it would be skipping the most recent in the inbox and going to the next email with the matching subject line?

Comment: You need to `Sort` the collection by the `RecievedTime` to get items ordered.

Comment: `Items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, iterating over all items in a folder is not really a good and right idea. You need to use the `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the Items class to get only items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

In the code posted above I've noticed the following line:

```
Set olMail = olInb.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = ""*Blue Recruit Req Data*""")
```

Be aware, the `Restrict` methods return an instance of the `Items` class which contains a collection of items that correspond to your condition, not a single item as you could think. For example:

```
Sub MoveItems()  
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder  
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
    Set myFolder = _  
        myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items  
    Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict("[Subject] = ""*Blue Recruit Req Data*""")  
    For i =  myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1  
        myRestrictItems(i).Move myFolder.Folders("Business")  
    Next  
End Sub
```

Also, I'd change the filter string to include entries that may contain the passed substring:

```
filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " LIKE '%" & wordsInSubject & " %'"
```

To get items ordered, i.e. start from the recent or oldest ones you need to sort the collection by using the `Sort` methods of the `Items` class:

```
Items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]")
```

Finally, you may also find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, `Instant Search` keywords can be used if `Instant Search` is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about the `AdvancedSearch` method and find the sample code in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Answer (score 1):

I have refactored some of your code so you can take advantage of calling procedures and organize your logic.

I didn't include all of your code though, but as I can see, you have enough knowledge to make it work.

A couple of suggestions:

1- Use `option explicit` at the top of your modules
2- Try to define your variables to something meaningful (use names anybody can understand)
3- Try to indent your code consistently (you could use [RubberDuck](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation)

**Before pasting your code:**

Use [early binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) to set the reference to Outlook object library and take advantage of intellisense and other benefits

1) Click on tools | References

[image]

2) Check the Microsoft Outlook XXX Object Library

[image]

---

**Here is the refactored code:**

Execute it using `F8` key and adjust it to fit your needs

```
Public Sub CheckEmail_BlueRecruit()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outlookNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim outlookFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim filterKeywords As String
    Dim filter As String

    ' Init objects
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set outlookNamespace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set outlookFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Init other variables
    filterKeywords = "financial"
    filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " LIKE '%" & filterKeywords & " %'"


    ' Loop through folders
    LoopFolders outlookFolder, filter


End Sub

Private Sub LoopFolders(ByVal outlookFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, ByVal filter As String)

    ' DeclareObjects
    Dim outlookSubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

    ProcessFolder outlookFolder, filter

    If outlookFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each outlookSubFolder In outlookFolder.Folders
            LoopFolders outlookSubFolder, filter
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFolder(ByVal outlookFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, ByVal filter As String)

    Dim outlookItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

    ' Filter folder
    Set outlookItems = outlookFolder.Items.Restrict(filter)

    If Not outlookItems Is Nothing Then

        For Each outlookMail In outlookItems

            If outlookMail.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then

                Debug.Print outlookMail.Subject

            End If

        Next outlookMail

    End If

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works and you need any more help